# Inequality with the difference of ceil functions

Tags: inequality, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I am interested in the validation of the inequality 
$$ \lceil x \rceil -  \lceil y \rceil \leqslant \lceil x-y \rceil $$
where $x, y$ are assumed to be positive.

Can someone help me to proof it?

Comment: You need to use *backward* slashes when formatting.

Comment: Try writing $x=m+\alpha,y=n+\beta$, where $0\le\alpha<1$ and $0\le\beta<1$ (and $m,n$ are integers).

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks for correction! So far, I've tried to use the upper and lower bounds of the ceiling function, but I did not accomplish to proof it.

Comment: @almagest: How would you continue with your approach?

Comment: @N.Younger Write down the lhs and rhs in terms of $m,n,\alpha,\beta$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x\le\lceil x \rceil< x+1\Rightarrow \lceil x \rceil<x+1$

$y\le\lceil y \rceil< y+1 \Rightarrow -\lceil y \rceil \le -y$

$\Rightarrow \lceil x\rceil-\lceil y\rceil < x-y+1 \le \lceil x-y\rceil+1$

How $\lceil x\rceil-\lceil y\rceil$ and $\lceil x- y\rceil+1$ are integers, then  $\lceil x\rceil-\lceil y\rceil < \lceil x-y\rceil+1 \Rightarrow \lceil x\rceil-\lceil y\rceil \le \lceil x-y\rceil$.

Comment: Why is $\lceil x \rceil - \lceil y \rceil$ an integer less than $x-y+1$? Since for $x=2.5$ and $y=1.8$ it is not true, because $\lceil x \rceil - \lceil y \rceil=1$ and $x-y+1=1.7$.

Comment: Sorry, it's wrong. I already corrected

Comment: No problems! :) I can understand the proof well. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Note $y\le \lceil y\rceil$ and $x-y\le\lceil x-y\rceil$, so (by adding those two inequalities):

$$x=y+(x-y)\le\lceil y\rceil+\lceil x-y\rceil$$

Thus, $\lceil y\rceil+\lceil x-y\rceil$ is *one* integer greater than or equal $x$. $\lceil x\rceil$ is the *smallest* such integer. Therefore $\lceil x\rceil\le\lceil y\rceil+\lceil x-y\rceil$, which is equivalent to what you have to prove.